# Fullcalendar jquery plugin loading times after selecting and inserting new events

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar plugin for our users to set their available times. Now everything works fine when reloading the page and when user adds one event, but when they add another event or start selecting, the page almost frozes. I tried all the solutions I found out on Stack but nothing.

I tried `calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', response.new_events);`  to add only the new events returned, but lag persist. Tried removing all the eventRender functions, but still the same result. Only thing that seems to work is when I reload the page after each event insert.

IS there any way to decrease the lag while adding new eventSource after select?

These are the parts of my `calendar js` code

```
eventSources: [{
        url: '/nanny/calendar/availability/all',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
            $(".loading-icon").hide();
            console.log(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
        },

    }],
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        var delete_icon = '<i style="float: right; cursor: pointer;" class="' + event.icon + '"></i>';
        if (event.icon) {
            element.find("div.fc-time").append(delete_icon);
        }
    },
eventAfterRender: function (event, $el, view) {
        $(".loading-icon").hide();
        var formattedTime = $.fullCalendar.formatRange(event.start, event.end, "HH:mm");
        // if event has fc-short class, data-start value will be displayed
        // remove fc-short class and update fc-time span text
        if ($el.is('.fc-short')) {
            $el.find(".fc-time span").text(formattedTime + " - " + event.title);
            $el.removeClass('fc-short');
            $el.find('.fc-title').remove();
        }
    },
    select: function (start, end) {

        //in the past so give error
        if (start.isBefore(moment())) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            return false;
        }

        //get the event data
        eventData = {
            start: moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
            end: moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        };
        if (eventData) {
                    if (eventData) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/nanny/calendar/store",
                data: eventData,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    swal({
                        title: "Yay",
                        text: response.msg,
                        type: "success",
                        showCancelButton: false,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#e36159",
                        confirmButtonText: "CLose",
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    });

                    calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', response.new_events);

                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
                    console.log(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
                }
            });
        }
        }
    },
```

**EDIT**

Here's the video.
[Lag example](https://youtu.be/XiGnIns7Ejk)

Comment: why are you adding a whole new event source just for one event? You can just use the `renderEvent` method to place a single extra event on the calendar. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/. Event Sources are intended for adding whole new lists of events from another URL and keeping them in sync.

Comment: @ADyson I am splitting the event into one hour interval in database so the user could delete times in the middle. Event with renderEvents, the lag still persists

Comment: how long does the Post request to /nanny/calendar/store take?

Comment: @ADyson its funny. first post request is instant and every other post request is 1 seconds slower. so let's say first one is 10ms, next one is 100 ms

Comment: @ADyson no it is not the post request because the lag is bigger every time I start selecting new event time. so first select is fast, and every other one is a lot slower

Comment: how many events are being displayed in the calendar already when this time lag occurs?

Comment: @ADyson let's say I reload the page right? There are 13 events are in the calendar. I select new event and store it which is fast. I use renderEvents to add the new events to the calendar. The next time I start selecting, the lag begins. If I reload, the lag is gone.

Comment: @ADyson also to clarify, the lag is still there even if I don't split the event into 1 hour events. :(

Comment: And exactly when is this lag? It starts when, and ends when? Is it starting when you begin to drag to select an event, or just after the call to renderEvents is made, or what? Are there any errors/warnings in the console? I'm not finding it easy to reproduce your problem. What version of fullCalendar, jQuery and momentJS are you using? Any other JS libraries on the page as well?

Comment: @ADyson   It start, like you said, when I begin to drag to select an event and then I have to wait for 2-3 seconds (the more events I have selected, the bigger the lag is), and then I get the success message, I press okay and then the lag is gone. I will try to get you a gif. give me few seconds.

Comment: @ADyson kindly see the edit

Comment: I don't have time right now but later I will try to replicate. There is a lot of event data there. It would really help and save some time if you could paste some sample event data somewhere I can make use of it, in the kind of volumes you're experiencing there. e.g. if you can paste on http://myjson.com/ a copy of the event JSON (e.g. with several hours-worth of events) you're getting back from your /nanny/calendar/store method and send the link to it then I can use that as a fake data source for my demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single event should be added using the `renderEvent` method. Create the event struct using the appropriate input and pass it to the `renderEvent` method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/nanny/calendar/store",
    data: eventData,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (response) {  
        var myEvent =
        {
            id: response.ID,
            title: response.TITLE,
            start: eventData.start,
            end: eventData.end,
        };

        $( "#calendar" ).fullCalendar( "renderEvent", myEvent );
    }
});
```

According to the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) the `start`, `end`, and `title` attributes are required. If you are not collecting a title you can hardcode it to something such as "Event".

If you are updating your events in a db and want to allow your users to modify an event (ie. drag and drop, resize, etc.) without refreshing/reloading the calendar you must also provide the `id` attribute. This can be the unique key assigned to the meeting when stored in the database. You will want to pass this value back in the ajax response. If this functionality is not necessary, then you can ignore the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**refetchEvents recall the function CalendarApp.prototype.init and refresh the calendar **

```
$.ajax({
          url: "BASE_URL",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(dataEvent),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(data) {

            window.swal({
              title: "Checking...",
              text: "Please wait",
              buttons: false,
              timer: 2000
            });
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents",dataEvent);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please, could you add some explanations to your answer. It would be really nice for the question owner and people who have the same problem.

Comment: Like This Martin

Comment: Not really, add some comments, an introduction. Why is it not working for the owner ? And what did you do to make it work ?
The goal is to not give code for copy-pasting, but for understanding how to do ;)

Comment: Nevermind, you'll do it better next time ;) Take a look at the Nick RB answer. An introduction, some references, and some advice.

Comment: ok j'envoyer-vous une invitation sur linkedin , quand vous avez un probleme :)

Comment: I'm completely fine, I didn't ask for any help. I was just reviewing your answer.